# A field is missing in reference

Tags: bibtex

I cannot figure out what is the problem with my bibitem:

```
@article{wraith1974,
author  = {Wraith, G.},
title   = {Artin Glueing},
year    = {1974},
journal = {Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra},
volume  = {4},
issue = {1},
pages   = {345-358}
}
```

My output is without **issue** field, as follows:

[image]

I am currently using Overleaf.com with `easychair` style.
Any sudgestion what might go wrong?
This particular output was obtained with `\bibliographystyle{plain}` but I also tryed to fix it with other styles too.

What is worse is that it did work in other projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `issue` is not a field defined by *any* bibliography style I'm familiar with, including `plain` and `abbrv`.

The fix? Simply replace `issue = {1},` with `number = {1},`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@article{wraith1974,
author  = {Wraith, G.},
title   = {Artin Glueing},
year    = {1974},
journal = {Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra},
volume  = {4},
number  = {1},
pages   = {345--358}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{cite} % citation management package, numerical style
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh my god!
Thank you very much!
I checked the other project where I thought it worked and I was wrong, you are right, issue does not work with plain, acm, e.t.c